# Aplicar validación requerida en varios mat-select dentro de una tabla

Tags: angular

Tengo una tabla con varios `mat-select` y quiero añadir una validación de **required** en cada uno. Pero debido a que se genera una tabla con varias filas este control sería el mismo para cada fila. Entonces solo me valida un `mat-select`, como podría agregar esa validación de manera independiente como si fuera un control distinto para cada fila. No sé si sea posible.

[image: tabla]

El .HTML es el siguiente

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Opciones</th>
      <th>Descripciones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dataDescripciones let i = index">
      <td>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-select formControlName="ctrlOpcion" placeholder="Select">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let op of dataOpciones" [value]="op.id">
              {{op.opcion}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="onCtrlValidate('ctrlOpcion','required')">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
      <td>{{row.descripcion}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table><br>
</form>
```

Y el .TS

```
dataOpciones = [
  { id: 12, opcion: 'Opcion 1' },
  { id: 13, opcion: 'Opcion 2' },
  { id: 14, opcion: 'Opcion 3' }
  //etc
];
dataDescripciones = [
  { id: 1, descripcion: 'Dato 1' },
  { id: 2, descripcion: 'Dato 2' },
  { id: 3, descripcion: 'Dato 3' }
  //etc
];
form: FormGroup;
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    ctrlOpcion: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
onCtrlValidate(name: any, error: any): FormControlDirective {
  return <FormControlDirective>this.form.controls[name].errors?.[error]
}
```

Subí una demo en la página de stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvvckf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso puedes crear un `FormControl` para cada `mat-select` de la tabla:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({})
   // 1. Crear un nuevo control por cada registro de la tabla y asignarle un correlativo
   for(let i = 0; i < this.dataDescripciones.length; i++){
    this.form.addControl('ctrlOpcion' + i,this.fb.control('', Validators.required))
   }

  }
```

---

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Opciones</th>
      <th>Descripciones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dataDescripciones let i = index">
      <td>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <!-- 2. Asignar ese control con su respectivo correlativo -->
          <mat-select formControlName="ctrlOpcion{{i}}" placeholder="Select">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let op of dataOpciones" [value]="op.id">
              {{op.opcion}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <!-- 2. Asignar ese control con su respectivo correlativo -->
          <mat-error *ngIf="onCtrlValidate('ctrlOpcion' + i,'required')">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
      <td>{{row.descripcion}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table><br>
</form>
```

Puedes ver una demo [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmygnb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).